# SonarLint v 3.0.0.1569 not displaying JavaScript Issues

Tags: javascript, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I am using SonarLint v 3.0.0.1569 with Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. SonarLint seems to be working perfectly with C# code, but for JavaScript code, I get the squiggly green underscore indicating an issue, but neither when I hover nor when I press + do I get the message about the issue.

I did get the "Activate support for JavaScript" message and said "yes". If I go to Tools | Options | SonarLint, everything looks good (i.e., the button to Deactivate JavaScript support is displayed). Am I missing something or is this just a bug or ???

Comment: Do you see the warning in the error window?

Comment: No, I've not seen any warnings in the error window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep opened all your Javascript files in VisualStudio, which are need to be analyzed and then build your solution. You'll get all javascript errors in ErrorList Window (Under Errors)

Note: Make sure Tools | Options | SonarLint | Javasript is Activated

Comment: Yes, some of our older js files are too complicated for it and it dies. Thanks.